# Highlight terms & condition checkbox in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to highlight the terms & condition checkbox on my woocommerce checkout page when the customer tries to buy but hasn't checked the box yet. 
I'm using this code for the input fields:

```
.woocommerce-invalid-required-field input {
    outline: 2px solid red!important;
}
```

But can't find a solution for the checkbox.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What way do you want to highlight it? What have you tried?

Comment: can you show us the site and tell us how you want it to look ?

Comment: I just want to highlight the checkbox with a red color to make the customer aware that this field is missing when he tries to pay and it isn't checked. So when he forgets to check the checkbox but hits the order button, I want to make him aware of the missing part. https://thewoodwave.de/shop/big-wave You have to go to the checkout to see my problem

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by adding the class `validate-required` to the `p` element in `woocommerce/checkout/terms.php` template

and then adding the css to mark it:

```
.woocommerce-invalid-required-field input {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

I know this is an old question but since google led me here in search of a solution I thought I'd offer it.